# Как создать ссылку на модель если она определена после django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две модели Style и Room. В первой из них нужна связь с другой, но я не могу ее создать, так как другая определена после. Поменять местами тоже не получится, так как во второй есть связь многие ко многим с первой

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Style(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    img = models.ImageField()
    walls = models.TextField()
    floor = models.TextField()
    roof = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Стили'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Стили'

class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    styles = models.ManyToManyField(Style)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комнаты'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комнаты'


class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Указать название модели в кавычках, строкой.

Comment: @andreymal Не желаете оформить как ответ? Хотя я уже знаю :-)

Answer (score 1):

Указывай название модели в кавычках, например в модели `Style` это будет так:

```py
rooms = models.ManyToManyField('Room', related_name='room_styles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```